# How to get PHP Submit button to link to a new page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have written an HTML form which asks users to answer some multiple choice questions. At the end, I have a submit button (using input type = button) and all the necessary php code to submit the multiple choice answers to a MySQL database. 
I want the Submit button to send the multiple choice answers to the database AND link to a new page with more questions. I got the link part working using an onClick event.

But the data doesn't get submitted. Right now I'm trying this:

```
<input type=button onClick="submitData()" name = "submit" value="Next ->">

<script>
function submitData() {
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
</script>
```

Then my PHP code starts with:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); ...
```

I thought that the isset function would check to see if the button had been pressed, but I don't think this is the case. Any ideas?

(btw, I originally used the "input type = submit" option and I was able to send the data to the database using that. But I couldn't get the "input type=submit" button to work as a link to a new page, so I thought I'd try using "input type=button")

Comment: you need to include more of your code, what you have posted is incomplete

Comment: the submit button doesn't link anywhere. it just submits the form to wherever the `<form>`'s action attribute points to. and the above code is rather pointless, since it's doing in JS what the submit button would do automatically anyways.

Comment: are you using ajax to submit form?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to `name="submit"` in the submit button. All the inputs in a form are properties of the form, and their names are the property names. So `document.getElementById("form1").submit` is this `<input>` element, which hides the `submit()` method inherited from the prototype.

Simply change the name of this element and it should work.

```
<input type=button onClick="submitData()" name = "submitData" value="Next ->">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form can be directed to another page when submitted with the `action`-attribute, such as below.

```
<form action="next_question.php" method="post">
```

Then you can fill the contents of `next_question.php` with the new questions, and also insert the information you wanted into the database on the same page.

Comment: Note that if you want to repopulate the form on error (when a field is incorrect), it is actually better to post to the current page, process & insert the values on the current page, and only do a redirect in PHP only if everything went ok (this is called *redirect after post*).

Comment: It depends on what kind of errors you are expecting in your form. You can do some error-checking via HTML-attributes on your form itself. And if there's output before this code can at all be processed, usage of `header`-redirecting in PHP isn't possible. Although I agree with you that one should check for errors, it's not always needed to be done in PHP. OPs form was "multiple choice answers", so I'm just assuming a bunch of checkboxes or radio-buttons.

Comment: It is **always** needed to be done in PHP. Client-side error checking can be bypassed, and therefore should never be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your PHP code in place for collecting the first page of answers; after you have saved to the DB you can redirect to the other page by using:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
die();
```